# .NET Core 5 Razor Pages Cookie Authentication redirects to the login page after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I created an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web app with "Individual authentication". I then added the Identity scaffolding and ran the application, it asked for "Apply Migration" I did it. I then registered a user and logged in with that user. Everything went as smoothly.

After successful login, the application landed on the Index page.

But the problem happened when I marked my "**Index.cshtml.cs**" page with **[Authorize]** attribute and added cookie settings in my startup.cs file.
The application started redirecting back to login page after successful login.

The expected behavior is that it should redirect to the Home page i.e Index.cshtml.

I checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372573/asp-net-core-razor-pages-cookie-authentication-redirects-to-the-login-page-after) and others but nothing is working for me.

I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

Here is my **startup.cs** file

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;

                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                {
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                    IsEssential = true,
                    HttpOnly = true
                };
                options.Cookie.Name = "Authentication";
            });

            services.AddAuthorization();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Does your `ApplicationDbContext` inherit `IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: Yes, It inherits from IdentityDbContext.

Comment: @Ortund Any idea on this ? The whole day has passed but still I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: I think the cookie is the issue; I'm almost positive it is. Your login succeeds and builds the cookie, but the logic behind `[Authorize]` isn't looking for *that* cookie to determine if the user is authenticated. As far as the majority of the site is concerned, your user is still anon

Comment: I'm afraid I have no suggestions for you to address this

Comment: I agree with you. It seems the Authorize tag is not looking for cookie. I tried all the settings nothing works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know the exact reason but changing the default authentication scheme worked for me.
In your startup.cs file, change
from this:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;

                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                {
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                    IsEssential = true,
                    HttpOnly = true
                };
                options.Cookie.Name = "Authentication";
            });
```

to this:

```
             services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;

                    options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                    {
                        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                        SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                        IsEssential = true,
                        HttpOnly = true
                    };
                    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
                });
```